# Django REST Framework: Nested Serializers not appearing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble with nested serializers and the Django rest framework.
When setting serializer_class to "UserSerializer", the nested data from the "NameSerializer" class isn't appearing.
However, when I set serializer_class to "NameSerializer", the data does appear.

The API returns when using UserSerializer:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "admin@admin.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "2@admin.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userName": "3@admin.com"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "userName": "4@admin.com"
  }
]
```

What I want it to return:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "userName": "admin@admin.com"
    "name": {
      "familyName": "Joe",
      "givenName": "admin",
      "formated": "admin Joe"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "userName": "jane@admin.com"
    "name": {
      "familyName": "Doe",
      "givenName": "Jane",
      "formated": "Jane Doe"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "userName": "Billy@admin.com"
    "name": {
      "familyName": "Idol",
      "givenName": "Billy",
      "formated": "Billy Idol"
    },
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "userName": "User@admin.com"
    "name": {
      "familyName": "B",
      "givenName": "User",
      "formated": "User B"
    },
  }
]
```

**views.py**

```
from API.models import Person
from API.serializers import *
from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Person.objects.all()
   serializer_class = NameSerializer
```

**models.py**

```
class Person(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
       verbose_name='email address',
       max_length=255,
       unique=True,
       )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    last_name =  models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class NameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  familyName = serializers.CharField(source='last_name')
  givenName = serializers.CharField(source='first_name')
  formatted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  class Meta:
      model = Person
      fields = ('familyName', 'givenName', 'formatted',)


  def get_formatted(slef, obj):
      FullName = obj.first_name + '' + obj.last_name
      return FullName


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  name = NameSerializer(many=True, readonly=True)
  userName = serializers.EmailField(source='email')

  class Meta:
      model = Person
      fields = ('id', 'userName', 'name')
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to create `NameSerializer` serializer. Create a method field in `UserSerializer` for `name` field such as:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    userName = serializers.EmailField(source='email')
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'userName', 'name')

    def get_name(self, obj):
        name = {
            'familyName': obj.first_name,
            'givenName': obj.last_name,
            'formatted': obj.first_name + ' ' + obj.last_name
        }
        return name
```

It will give your desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):
Something like this:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    userName = serializers.EmailField(source='email')
    name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'userName', 'name')

    def get_name(self, obj):
        return {
            'familyName': obj.first_name,
            'givenName': obj.last_name,
            'formatted': obj.first_name + ' ' + obj.last_name
        }
```

Comment: I get the exact same result. The "name" key still doesn't show up.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

`class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     name = NameSerializer()
     userName = serializers.EmailField(source='email')`

```
     class Meta:
         model = Person
         fields = ('id', 'userName', 'name')
```

If the items should be a list, then only you need to pass `many=True`.

Comment: When making the above changes I get the following error  "Class UserSerializer missing "Meta" attribute"

If I add the Meta class back, I get the error "Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer `UserSerializer`."

Comment: @dev_null The issue here is that in queryset of your views, you are passing   data from model **Person**. In the model, there is no reference to the **NameSerializer**.